# Filling gaps in time series data

Tags: haskell, datetime, functional-programming

My Haskell set/map/list folds often become terse and difficult to read.  I'm looking for tips on how to make my functional code easier to follow.

I'm working around a bug/feature in a plotting library.  I have a map from tags to lists of (time,count) which I plot as a stacked graph:

```
import           Data.Time (UTCTime)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Set as S

type CountMap = M.Map String [(UTCTime, Int)]

-- Data used for plotting data series 'foo' and 'bar'
test :: CountMap
test = 
  M.fromList [ ("foo", [(read "2012-09-28 12:00:00", 3), (read "2012-09-29 12:00:00", 4)])
             , ("bar", [(read "2012-09-28 12:00:00", 3)])
             ]
```

You will note that the above "bar" series is missing a sample for 2012-09-29.  I need to fill these gaps with zeros before I pass the data to the plotting library.

The same data with the gaps closed becomes:

```
fromList [ ("bar",[(2012-09-28 12:00:00 UTC,3),(2012-09-29 12:00:00 UTC,0)])
         , ("foo",[(2012-09-28 12:00:00 UTC,3),(2012-09-29 12:00:00 UTC,4)])]
```

The code I use for filling the gaps with zero samples is as follows:

```
import           Data.Time (UTCTime)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Set as S

-- Insert zero counts into date buckets that are missing a sample.
substZeroCount :: CountMap -> CountMap
substZeroCount m =
  M.map zeros m
  where
    allDates = M.fold (flip (foldr (\(date,_) -> S.insert date))) S.empty m

    zeros cs = M.toList $ S.fold insertMissing (M.fromList cs) allDates

    insertMissing date acc = if M.member date acc then acc else M.insert date 0 acc
```

It works and it's not even too long.  But somehow I don't feel happy about its readability.  It looks somehow too terse.  Maybe it's just about code layout.. or perhaps there'd be a nicer way to compose these functions.  Or maybe it's just because a lot happens in 3 lines of code. ;)

Any suggestions on how to make `substZeroCount` easier on the eyes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should keep `CountMap` as `Map String (Map UTCTime Int)`. That is a better way of keeping counts. If you do that then you can use `mysc` function directly. I find `mysc` much more readable and clear.

```
import           Data.Time (UTCTime)
import qualified Data.Map as M

type CountMap = M.Map String [(UTCTime,Int)]

-- Data used for plotting data series 'foo' and 'bar'
test :: CountMap
test =
  M.fromList [ ("foo", [(read "2012-09-28 12:00:00", 3), (read "2012-09-29 12:00:00", 4)])
             , ("bar", [(read "2012-09-28 12:00:00", 3)])
             ]

susetCount :: CountMap -> CountMap
susetCount = M.map M.toList . mysc . M.map M.fromList
mysc m =  M.map (flip M.union allelems) m
 where
    -- Find all possible UTCTime that can exist. 
    allelems = M.map (const 0) $ M.foldr' M.union M.empty m
```

Comment: Nice!  You probably mean M.fold instead of M.foldr'?

Comment: Nurpax: Yeah you can use M.fold with some changes but this will also work .

Comment: At least my Data.Map doesn't have a `foldr'`, only `fold`, hence the question.  Replacing `M.foldr'` above with M.fold works without any other changes.

Comment: @Nurpax You might have been using older version of containers. It now has that. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.1/doc/html/Data-Map.html#v:foldr-39-

Comment: Gotcha, I was running an old HP.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Nurpax Also just to mention that use fold is now deprecated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5978/discussion-between-nurpax-and-satvik)